# How do I get suspend working on a Sony Vaio P?

Tags: 12.04, suspend, gma500

Suspend has always been a problem in the Sony Vaio P (with the famous gma500 graphics chip). In Oneiric, coming back from suspend meant a black screen. This could be fixed by following the advice in https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42119 which implied adding `--quirk-vbe-post --quirk-vbemode-restore` in the pm configuration.

In Precise, after suspend the black screen is still there and adding the previous quirks results in a garbled screen that cannot be changed even moving to tty1. Any ideas about how suspend can be fixed here?

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu it ask's if you want your home partition to be encrypted or not, if you chose so the swap partition will also be encrypted. The problem with the  encrypted swap is that it does not support well suspend or hibernate. So you can check for start if the swap is or not encrypted.

Comment: Thanks. My home partition is not encrypted, though...

Answer (score 0):

I did not know this fix and suspend never worked for me in 11.10.
However, I now tried to apply it and got a "blue glittering screen".
Then, I removed the first quirk, leaving only "--quirk-vbemode-restore" and it magically (i couldn't believe it) worked!

for noobs:
in terminal type `sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/gma500`
a blank file will open, put in it `ADD_PARAMETERS='--quirk-vbemode-restore'`
then save

this worked on an acer ao751h with the same gma500 graphics